# How to use bodybuilder to generate a dynamic query from frontend?

Tags: elasticsearch, query-builder

I'm using [bodybuilder](http://bodybuilder.js.org/) to generate the elasticsearch query but I don't know how to create a complex query with query, filter and all.

Suppose I have fields in an array

```
let queryArr =
[
  {
    type: 'query',
    field: 'message',
    input: 'this is a test'    
  },
  {
    type: 'filter',
    field: 'user',
    input: 'sample'    
  },
  {
    type: 'notfilter',
    field: 'user',
    input: 'demo'    
  },
  {
    type: 'query',
    field: 'name',
    input: 'test'    
  }
]
```

How can I generate the below final query structure to be passed to bodybuilder from this array ?

```
let finalQuery = bodybuilder()
        .query('match', 'message', 'this is a test')
        .filter('term', 'user', 'sample')
        .notFilter('term', 'user', 'demo')
        .query('match', 'name', 'test')
        .build()
```

Here bodybuilder and build are functions provided by bodybuilder.

I tried using template strings but it didn't work.

**I'm open to suggestions for any other client side JS querybuilder which takes array as input and returns an elasticsearch query.**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a couple of days ago but I found a way to work with bodybuilder, but you need the function.. term/match etc as well

```
        const ds = bodybuilder()
        queryArr.forEach((element) => {
            ds[element.type](element.function, element.field, element.input);
        });
        const build = ds.build();
```

and the query builds just fine. except if you need nested aggregations/filters which this approach wont work